# Search function returning nothing -Django

Tags: django, search, django-templates

```
def Search(request):
  if request.method == 'GET' and request.GET['x']:
    parameter = request.GET['x']
    results = Category.objects.filter(advert__Seller_Name__icontains = parameter)
    return render(request, 'campusbuy/search.html', {'results': results})

else:
    return render(request, 'campusbuy/search.html')
```

Above is my search function. When I try to search for an object in my template, it returns nothing.  However, when I deliberately search for a Seller_name that's not in the db it returns the {% else %} value. Below is the template:

```
% extends 'campusbuy/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if results %}


    {% for ads in results.advert_set.all %}
        <p>{{ads.Seller_Name }}</p>
        <p>{{ads.Location}}</p>
        <p>{{ads.Description}}</p>
        <p>{{ads.Asking_Price}}</p>

     {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    <p>No Ad matched your search criteria.</p>

{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Here's the models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):

Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
Details = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Default")
Category_Logo = models.ImageField(max_length=100, upload_to='uploads')

def __str__(self):
    return self.Name

class Advert(models.Model):

HALL3 = 'HALL3'
HALL4 = 'HALL4'
HALL2 = 'HALL2'
MAIN_GATE = 'MAINGATE'
HALL1 = 'HALL1'

Location_Choices = (
    (HALL3, 'Hall3'),
    (HALL4, 'Hall4'),
    (HALL2, 'Hall2'),
    (MAIN_GATE, 'Main_gate'),
    (HALL1, 'Hall1')
)

category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Seller_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
Phone_Number = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False, null=False,
                                help_text='<p style="color: red; font: italic 12px tahoma;">**Please input a working Phone Number that you can be contacted with on the fly</p>')
image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, upload_to='uploads')
Item = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
Location = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Location_Choices, default=HALL3, blank=False)
Description = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
Asking_Price = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, default=timezone.now)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `results` is a queryset, it doesn't have an `advert_set` attribute; only the elements *in* the queryset have that attribute. But it's not clear what you actually want to output here, you need to show your models.

Comment: I added the models, I believe the question should be perspicuous now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you have involved Category in the query at all. You don't use it to filter, and you don't use it in the display, so why use it? Why not query Advert directly?

Comment: I tried that already, it still returned nothing. I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: *What* did you try? Show the code. But also explain why you used Category.

Comment: I used Category because it has a many to one relationship with Adverts. I used examples from  Django's official site https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Argh. You're not using it. Why did you query it?

Comment: I'm pretty new to django, if you have a solution kindly point it out to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't understood why you've tried to include Category in the query, since you are not using it at all either in the query itself or in the template. Just query and use Adverts directly:

```
results = Advert.objects.filter(Seller_Name__icontains=parameter)
```

and iterate over it also directly:

```
{% for ads in results %}
    <p>{{ads.Seller_Name }}</p>
    <p>{{ads.Location}}</p>
    <p>{{ads.Description}}</p>
    <p>{{ads.Asking_Price}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

Also note, you don't need the `if` block, because the `for template tag has an [`empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) clause that is displayed if the loop was empty:

```
{% for ads in results %}
    <p>{{ads.Seller_Name }}</p>
    <p>{{ads.Location}}</p>
    <p>{{ads.Description}}</p>
    <p>{{ads.Asking_Price}}</p>
{% empty %}
    <p>No Ad matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel Roseman for your time. I still got the same error anyway,I decided to use Elasticsearch instead and it's working just fine. Thanks for your contribution!